# Why can't we store all strings in String pool?

Tags: java, string, memory

If string pool helps to save memory, why we can't store all strings there? 
In what cases we have to creare String through `new String()` ?

Comment: Do you realise just how many different strings you'd need to store, to store _all_ the strings?

Comment: Think about reading a big file into a single `String`, if that would be interned you'd have just a multi KB big String lying around in memory

Answer (score 2):

You say:

> It helps save memory

Sure it helps save memory in a specific case. It helps save memory when you have a String that is going to be reused multiple times. Obviously, it will be the same String in memory.

Now, why would you add all the string you use to this memory? Some of them might be defined just for computation and nothing else. If you keep every string you defined in memory, you will increase your memory usage without any good reason. It won't save any memory.

Keep that it mind: It saves memory only when strings are reused. Otherwise, it clutters the memory with low usage strings for no good reason.